# where to reference external js file in html button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm doing an exercise from a course in Udacity and they give us an html with its functions in javascript. The webpage consists of a form in which you write something and when you submit it then that is added to the page in a blue square. The point of this is to show us how the mvo design pattern works, so the js file is divided in the model, the view and the octopus which connects the two previous. Just to play around, I wanted to add a "remove" button that removed the last block in the page. I kind of coppied the function that added a new block, but used .pop() instead of .push() in order to manipulate the localstorage of the page. I think the function is correct, but I can't figure out how to "call" the function. I've tried to add an event listener to the button. I also tried to use .submit() from jquery with event.preventDefault(); to put the remove function as a parameter of .submit(). I think the closest option would be to reference the .js with  tags and then call the function inside the buttons onclick attribute, but it's not working (the function is a method of an object that is inside the .js, so I tried calling it like this `<button onclick = "javascript:octopus.remove()">remove!</button>`). Also tried using onclick but on javascript `document.getElementById("button").onclick = function(){};` but nothing. Any help? this is the js

```js
$(function(){

    var model = {
        init: function() {
            if (!localStorage.notes) {
                localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify([]);
            }
        },
        add: function(obj) {
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
            data.push(obj);
            localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        getAllNotes: function() {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
        },
        //here I tried everything but nothing seems to work
        remove: function() {
            document.getElementById("button").onclick = 
                function(){
                    var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
                    data.push(obj);
                    localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(data);
            };
        }

        
    };


    var octopus = {
        addNewNote: function(noteStr) {
            model.add({
                content: noteStr
            });
            view.render();
        },

        getNotes: function() {
            return model.getAllNotes().reverse();
        },

        init: function() {
            model.init();
            view.init();
        },
        
        removeNote: function(){
            model.remove();
            view.render();
        }
    };


    var view = {
        init: function() {
            this.noteList = $('#notes');
            var newNoteForm = $('#new-note-form');
            var newNoteContent = $('#new-note-content');
            newNoteForm.submit(function(e){
                octopus.addNewNote(newNoteContent.val());
                newNoteContent.val('');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            view.render();

        },
        render: function(){
            var htmlStr = '';
            octopus.getNotes().forEach(function(note){
                htmlStr += '<li class="note">'+
                        note.content + 
                    '</li>';
            });
            this.noteList.html( htmlStr );
        },


    };

    octopus.init();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Udacity Retain</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/retain.css">
</head>
<body>    
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/retain.js"></script>
    
    <form id="new-note-form" class="new-note-form">
        <input id="new-note-content" class="new-note-content">
    </form>
    <button id = "button">remove!</button>
    
    <ul id="notes" class="notes"></ul>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are nearly there.. I've updated your code to work, see below.

Firstly, you need to make `model.remove()` actually delete an item by using `pop()` and then saving the updated data.

Secondly, you need to hook up a click event to the remove button. I've added this in `view.init()` after where you hook up the form submit.

```js
$(function(){

    var model = {
        init: function() {
            if (!localStorage.notes) {
                localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify([]);
            }
        },
        add: function(obj) {
            var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
            data.push(obj);
            localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(data);
        },
        getAllNotes: function() {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
        },
        // Updated method below
        remove: function() {
          var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.notes);
          data.pop();
          localStorage.notes = JSON.stringify(data);
        }        
    };


    var octopus = {
        addNewNote: function(noteStr) {
            model.add({
                content: noteStr
            });
            view.render();
        },

        getNotes: function() {
            return model.getAllNotes().reverse();
        },

        init: function() {
            model.init();
            view.init();
        },
        
        removeNote: function(){
            model.remove();
            view.render();
        }
    };


    var view = {
        init: function() {
            this.noteList = $('#notes');
            var newNoteForm = $('#new-note-form');
            var newNoteContent = $('#new-note-content');
            var removeBtn = $('#button');
            
            newNoteForm.submit(function(e){
                octopus.addNewNote(newNoteContent.val());
                newNoteContent.val('');
                e.preventDefault();
            });

            // Added click event on the remove button
            removeBtn.on('click', function() {
                octopus.removeNote();
            });

            view.render();

        },
        render: function(){
            var htmlStr = '';
            octopus.getNotes().forEach(function(note){
                htmlStr += '<li class="note">'+
                        note.content + 
                    '</li>';
            });
            this.noteList.html( htmlStr );
        },


    };

    octopus.init();
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Udacity Retain</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/retain.css">
</head>
<body>    
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/retain.js"></script>
    
    <form id="new-note-form" class="new-note-form">
        <input id="new-note-content" class="new-note-content">
    </form>
    <button id = "button">remove!</button>
    
    <ul id="notes" class="notes"></ul>



</body>
</html>
```